# HTML email re-sizes table column to fit contents rather than respecting cell width and wrapping text

Tags: html, html-table, html-email

I need your help.

Below is a perfect example of how the brower (IE10) renders my html table nicely. Should the contents of the cell be too long, the CSS properties for the word-wrap kicks in.:

[image]

Then, if I were to create the same page using the same HTML code MS Outlook 2007 renders my table to look like the following:

How can the HTML code be corrected such that it is rendered properly (i.e. the column widths are respected and that the long text is wrapped neatly?

Can there ever be harmony?

[image]

HTML code in question:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" height="100%" width="100%">
            <tr>
                <td align="center">
                    <table style="vertical-align: top; text-align: left; table-layout: fixed; word-wrap: break-word; border: 1px solid #000;" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="4" width="50%">
                        <tr>
                            <td style="width: 200px;">File Number:</td>
                            <td style="width: 200px;">'+ fileno +'</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Reference documents:</td>
                            <td>8425655,8417897,8417794,8425734,8425822,8417976,8417957,8427664,8555286,8555321</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you dont have space on the text, is being taken as "inline" object, thats why you cannot change line, plus, the width is 100%, so, will be as width as possible.